Can't import createApp from "vue"
So I've written the very basic App.vue file:
import { createApp } from "vue"
import App from "./App.vue"


createApp(App).mount("#app")

and it logs the error
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "vue". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Previously, I've ran npm install vue
in index.html, i've tried removing type="module" and it would return
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module


You're supposed to use a build tool when using from "vue" because browsers are clueless about node packages. You can't use .vue files without a build tool too

As the prev comment mentions, you need to build a vuejs project using something like Vite.  This includes running commands like: "npm run build" or "npm run dev". This will convert you vuejs code, to vanilla html,css,js which the browser does understand. This is a great place to get started: "https://vitejs.dev/guide/" Hope this helps, good luck!
